# Visual Studio: Where can I edit the dependencies of my android app?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm right now at monetizing my app. In order to do this, I need to do the following:

Import the Mobile Ads SDK

Apps can import the Google Mobile Ads SDK with a gradle dependency. Open the app-level build.gradle file for your app, and look for a "dependencies" section.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
}
```

I can absolutely NOT find this page where I can edit the dependencies. Can anyone hint me towards the right direction? THANKS :)

Comment: you are working on an android studio or  visual studio

Comment: visual studio, as i said in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin the dependencies need to be binded to C#. Luckily you do not have do that on your own for the Android Support AppCompat v7 and Play Services Ads because there are nuget packages:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/

Just right click "References" in your Xamarin Android project and click "Manage NuGet Packages" and install the packages mentioned above or make use of the package manager console.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didnt know that.. Now, when I try to install the packages this is what NuGet Tells me:
PM> Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 
Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

 ... whats that supposed to mean?

Comment: If you use the package manager console, you have to select the default project first (on top of the console you can find a dropdown) or you can use the other method I suggested above.

Comment: Okay, now this appears: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 42.1021.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0

Comment: okay i got that to work now. problem was the targeted version. but now that i have that installed, how do i proceed? :D is there a manual somewher? :)

Comment: Everything is mapped so you can follow the regular Android documentation, you just have to write the property names and the methods with a capital letter and Get/Set methods from java are often just mapped to a property in C#. Additionally the source code of the mapping is open source, this might help as well: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside your App Module you can find build.gradle file there you can write your dependency as.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.satyamanand.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: hello and thanks ! :) another noob question: where do i find my "App module" ? :)

Comment: File system - YourProject/app/build.gradle

Comment: im so sorry, i have NO CLUE what you mean... my project as in the file explorer of my windows? or "my project" while my project is open and then in the solution explorer? THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: Checkout the screen shot in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Inside Android Studio checkout the application Structure.]

Inside Android Studio checkout the application Structure.

Comment: I dont use Android Studio, I use Visual Studio - this is what it looks like: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=fd267f-1494849050.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can't find Gradle dependencies because you're not using Gradle, you're using xamarin which is not the same as native Android Development using Android Studio.

Looking at and Android Docs for this sort of thing will perhaps not be so useful.

I suggest you look [here at the Xamarin Google Play Services module](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-ads), this should get you started in the right direction.